# RuntimeException which occurs only in huawei devices that above android 8.0

Tags: android, android-8.0-oreo

I have got some crash logs in google play analysis, which occurs only in huawei devices , and the android version is above android 8.0 ,but i can't find the reason by the log because it's all happens in system codes, wish someone can help me .

the log is like this:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
at android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel (Native Method)
at android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel (InputChannel.java:148)
at android.view.InputChannel$1.createFromParcel (InputChannel.java:39)
at android.view.InputChannel$1.createFromParcel (InputChannel.java:37)
at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult.<init> (InputBindResult.java:68)
at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult$1.createFromParcel (InputBindResult.java:112)
at com.android.internal.view.InputBindResult$1.createFromParcel (InputBindResult.java:110)
at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodManager$Stub$Proxy.startInputOrWindowGainedFocus (IInputMethodManager.java:740)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.startInputInner (InputMethodManager.java:1347)
at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.onPostWindowFocus (InputMethodManager.java:1617)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage (ViewRootImpl.java:4189)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:108)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:166)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7425)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:245)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

Comment: I guess something is wrong the play API and nothing you can do about it.
because the log has no reference to your code.